# Change custom UITableViewCell text color

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I've had this come up a few times and each time I never find an "elegant" solution.

**Problem:**
I have a customer `UITableViewCell` with `XIB`, `InventoryCustomCell`. That cell has `UILabels`. The `UILabel`'s default text color is black. I have an array of indexs for rows where the `UILabel` text color needs to be gray. I have a public method in my `InventoryCustomCell` that allows me to set the color of the `UILabel` s.

That public method looks like this:

```
- (void)setCellAdded:(BOOL)cellAdded {

    UIColor *cellTextColor;
    if (cellAdded) {
        self.thumbImageView.alpha = 0.5f;
        cellTextColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    } else {
        self.thumbImageView.alpha = 1.0f;
        cellTextColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }

    self.titleLabel.textColor = cellTextColor;
    self.partNumberLabel.textColor = cellTextColor;
    self.priceLabel.textColor = cellTextColor;
    self.quanityLabel.textColor = cellTextColor;
    self.addButton.titleLabel.textColor = cellTextColor;
}
```

In my `UITableViewController` class, I register the class with the `XIB`.

```
[self.inventoryListTable registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"InventoryCustomCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"InventoryCustomCellID"];
```

In my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I set it like this:

```
InventoryCustomCell *cell = (InventoryCustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:inventoryCellID forIndexPath:indexPath];

.....
Product *product = .. is grabbed from NSFetchedResultsController

if ([addedProducts containsObject:product.objectID])
     [cell setCellAdded:YES];
else
     [cell setCellAdded:NO];

return cell;
```

Now if I add a breakpoint in `setCellAdded` the right `if` block is entered in order to set the cell label colors to gray. So I know that is actually being called.

What I think the issue here is, is that the table view is trying to reuse the cells and since they all have the same identifier it doesn't now which ones should be gray and which ones shouldn't. But if that were the case then i would expect to see some cells randomly gray and some not after `setCellAdded` is called the first time. That is not the case. None of the cell ever turn gray yet the call to turn them gray makes all the way.

If I was using default `UITableViewCell`s I would probably just have a separate `cellIdentifier` for black/gray ones. Since I am using a custom `UITableViewCell` that has a nib that I have to register for a single `cellIdentifier` I cannot use this method while keeping only one `XIB` file.

The only thing I have thought would work is if I created a new XIB with the same cell view but add all the labels be gray. Then I could use the two `cellIdentifier` approach but this just seems hacky.

Comment: Do these cells show up in the table with black text?

Comment: Yes they do show up as black

Comment: What happens if you don't do the registerNib method? What happens if you use `[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"InventoryCustomCell]`

Comment: If you do that you have to do the whole topLevelObjects thing to load the xib with the cell. As of iOS5 your suppose to use registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you're passing NO when you think you are

Comment: Yes, I've put a break point in setCellAdded add it is entering the correct part of the if block when it's suppose to. I've used customer cells a million times and have never had this issue. I'm not sure what the hell is going on.

Comment: Try moving the method to your tableViewController, and pass in the cell. `-(void)makeGrayCell:(InventoryCustomCell *)cell` . The only other thing I can think is you should wrap your if statement in brackets if () { } else { }

Comment: Doesn't fix it, still does the same thing.

Comment: The only other answer is that you are sending these messages to a nil object. Confirm in the debugger that your UILabels are not 0x00000

Comment: The labels are not nil. This is absolutely driving me insane. Everything is setup properly, I use the same setup for a different custom cell and it works fine. I really appreciate your help though.

Comment: How hard would it be for you to share the project files. Can you replicate it in a tiny project with one view? If you have another cell that works, you're missing something. If all else fails, burn one of your apple support incidents

Answer (score 0):

Just add properties for the UILabels in the .h file of your custom cell class. Then in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` do something like this:

```
InventoryCustomCell *cell = (InventoryCustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:inventoryCellID forIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.yourTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];

return cell;
```

Comment: I noticed that you use a string literal when registering your nib, and a string variable in dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier. Are you sure those string values are the same?

Comment: They are the same in both places

Comment: have you tried moving the textColor code to your cellForRow method?

Comment: Yes I have, still no luck >:(